# sql numbering the partition of Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of numbers like this

```
ID
===
1
2
3
1
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

I want to select a new row that increase when fetch next 1 like this

```
ID    number
===  ========
1        1
2        1
3        1
1        2
2        2
1        3
1        4
2        4
3        4
4        4
5        4
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: is there another column in your table that can use to determine the sequence ?

Comment: Just to add to Squirrel - without an ORDER, your sequence "stream" ordering isn't guaranteed (even with a [heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)) - you'll likely get different results each time you run it. Also, calling a non-unique column `Id` isn't very idiomatic :)

Comment: @Squirrel actually I was confused about how to do this at the moment. But I figured out that DENSE_RANK() can be use in my case and totally worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve this with use of cte and window functions, as follows:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

WITH cte AS(
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
  FROM @t
),
cte1 AS(
SELECT ID, rn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn) rn2
  FROM cte
  WHERE ID = 1
)
SELECT c.ID, MAX(rn2) OVER (ORDER BY c.rn) rn
  FROM cte c
  LEFT JOIN cte1 c1 ON c1.rn = c.rn
  ORDER BY c.rn
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` is just tricking the optimizer into not giving you an error message. `ORDER BY 1`, *rightly* gives you an error message, and there's no guarantee that the optimizer won't be improved in the future to see through your trickery and raise an error here. It **doesn't** give you any kind of ordering guarantee and so it's *meaningless*. This answer may *appear* to work but that's programming by *coincidence*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As you mentioned correctly, UNLESS there is another ordering column,  you have no guarantee that the sorting will be equal every time you execute it - but this was not the OPs question. `SELECT 1` should usually result in the order in which the records have been inserted. It is not meaningless, since otherwise ROW_NUMBER() would not be possible. Finally, as soon as there is another sortable column, the SELECT 1 can easily be replaced and the solution is still working!

Comment: It is meaningless. Try it with `ORDER BY 1` and read the error message. It tells you that ordering by a constant is pointless. You've just *hidden* the constant from the system - not supplied meaning.

Comment: actually the built-in function DENSE_RANK() was better for my case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a column `o` which specify the ordering then you can use a self-join like this:

```
select d1.o, d1.id, count(*)
from data d1
join data d2 on d1.o >= d2.o and d2.id = 1
group by d1.o, d1.id
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=106d406c7c165c5cd15afbeaeb150c89)